# Does a compact operator always have a kernel?

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators, integral-operators

I am sorry if this question is stupid..... I raise it when I read Lax's book Functional Analysis. We know that some integral operators are compact, for example an integral operator from $L^2[Y]$ to $L^2[X]$ defined by
   $$ (Kf)(x) = \int{K(x,y)f(y)dy}$$ 
is compact if $X$ and $Y$ are compact space and the kernel is square integrable. But how about the converse question? Does any compact operator from $L^2[Y]$ to $L^2[X]$ always has a kernel $K(x,y)\in{L^2}$? If not, under what conditions this compact operator have such kernel?

Moreover, how about other spaces, such as $C(X)$, $L^p$ space? (For genreal $L^p$ space, I am not sure this question is meaningful, since the above integral may diverge....)

Can anyone give me a hint or any references? Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

If you insist that $K$ must be square-integrable, then even on $L_2$ this is not true. Indeed, every such integral operator must be [Hilbert–Schmidt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_integral_operator) but there are plenty of compact operators which are not Hilbert–Schmidt. (For instance any diagonal operator with respect to a fixed orthonormal basis whose eigenvalues are not (square) summable but tend to 0.) See a related question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/70969/when-is-an-integral-transfrom-trace-class).